# Рефакторинг Delphi

Tags: ооп, delphi

Доброй ночи! Заниматься программированием я начал чуть более года назад, но дополз до классов только сейчас. С давних пор пишу игру с использованием OpenGl и еще совсем чуть-чуть и пойду изучать сокеты для сетевой составляющей.

Все я это писал в 3 модулях: Главная форма, Стандартные ф-ции, Ф-ции рисования. Все прекрасно работало хоть и было написано криво процедурным программированием. Хотелось бы привести код к хорошему виду. У меня есть собственно главное поле игры, в котором есть многие параметры, которые раньше вызывались из главной формы и уже в отдельном модуле рисования собственно выводились на экран. Сейчас же если я приведу к ООП то получится, что в 4-м модуле, связанном только с генерацией поля будет класс, который будет вызываться из модуля рисования, который в свою очередь будет вызываться из главной формы. По-моему бред.

Я пытаюсь главный модуль держать в чистоте, оставив в нем лишь только самое основное, а все собственно операции раскидать по другим частям. Как можете понять у меня это не выходит... Автор книги(Библия Delphi Фленов М.Е) советует держать поля закрытыми в private зоне, дабы не пускать глаза в ненужную часть. Но как собственно мне это сделать я не пойму.

В общем прошу небольшой помощи: как правильно организовать структуру большой и одновременно чистой программы с ООП.

*P.S скачал исходники WinDjView и там 109 модулей..... Я не могу связать между собой 4 модуля, а там 109....*

Comment: вам надо почитать про ООП, паттерны программирования. в любом случае рефакторить существующий работающий код часто чрезмерно сложная задача. вы придумали какие-то связки классов а применить к уже существующему коду крайне сложно. зачастую проще сделать наоборот. выделить основные сущности, приготовить классы, методы. а потом уже портировать функционал в спроэктированую архитектуру.

Comment: По-моему, здесь глобальная проблема. Во-первых, никто не обязывает использовать ООП. Дельфи вполне себе позволяет работать в процедурном ключе. Во-вторых, если уж делать ООП, то с умом. Т.е. проще сначала разработать структуру, а потом уже писать код. Получается, прогрпмму придется переписать с нуля. А выигрыш, на мой взгляд, будет не очень существенен.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Код хоть у меня и небольшой, но написан не совсем плохо. Лучше потрачу некоторое время, но сделаю прочный фундамент для дальнейших улучшений, нежели, спотыкаться и ломать голову с кривой структурой.

Comment: в свое время, когда только начал работать, мне нужно было вникнуть в один проект, в котором было около 40 модулей и по 1,5-2 тыс. строк кода на каждый. Разумеется была структура с многоуровневым наследованием. Так это я к чему? Мне книжка помогла хорошая, в которой идет объяснение ООП сразу для delphi и c++. Если надо, то могу сказать авторов и название, когда до дома доберусь.  

PS. по поводу исходников WinDjView - включаете режим отладки, берете какой-нибудь последний дочерний класс, и начинаете построчно прогонять его методы. и так все классы. по другому никак =/

Comment: teanЫЧ, обязательно жду названия книги)

Comment: Хорошо. Потому что все эти Библии делфи включают в себя слишком много, и слишком мало какой-либо конкретики. А тут целая книга посвящена ООП.

Comment: > реф**р**асторинг

Таки вам дорога книжку Фаулера читать.

Comment: @karmadro4, кто о чем...

Comment: @teanЫЧ, я об основах, eg. *зачем нужно делать пилинг*. А то вы на своих Флёновых далеко не уедете.

Comment: @karmadro4 ну то, что эти "Фленовы" плодят поколения быдлокодеров, я согласен. Но надо же с чего-то начинать? И многие считают эти книги расово верными. Хотя лично я дальше первых 20 страниц в таких произведениях не заходил, как-то интернетами обходился...

Comment: @teanЫЧ, таки возвращаемся к моему изначальному предложению прочитать хотя бы определение, а лучше первоисточники про рефакторинг и чистый и совершенный код.

Comment: teanЫЧ, обещали же название книжки оставить?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю, что в рамках короткого ответа можно рассказать то, чему посвящены толстые тома и за 15 минут научить тому, чему зачастую учатся месяцами...

Но пару зарисовок могу попробовать привести.

Первый совет - делайте всё маленькими шагами, иначе высок риск всё испортить.

Самый простой рефакторинг в плане переделки на классы - классовые функции:
было:

```
procedure DoSmth;
begin
  ...
end;

begin
  DoSmth;
end.
```

стало:

```
   type
    TSmthMaker = class(TObject)
    public
      class procedure DoSmth;
    end;

  class procedure TSmthMaker.DoSmth;
  begin
    ...
  end;

  begin
    TSmthMaker.DoSmth;
  end.
```

В чём даже на первых этапах может быть выигрыш, несмотря на то, что кода вроде как стало больше? Во-первых - более лёгкий переход к реальному ООП с наследованиями и так далее, об этом сейчас не стоит.

В такой реализации можно часть функционала перенести в секцию private для улучшения читабельности ну и как вы сказали, чтобы не пускать в глаза ненужное.

Простой пример, у вас процедура обработки таблицы, в ней вложенный цикл по строке и столбцу, внутри что-то делается. Вы можете завести глобальную функцию ProcessCell, чтобы вынести процедуру, обрабатывающую ячейку, но если у вас несколько функций обработки таблицы - высок риск запутаться. С помощью классов это будет выглядеть как-то так (привожу только интерфейсную часть, потому как и так длинно):

```
type
  TTableProcessor1 = class(TObject)
  private
    procedure ProcessCell(Col, Row: Integer);
  public
    procedure ProcessTable;
  end;

  TTableProcessor2 = class(TObject)
  private
    procedure ProcessCell(Col, Row: Integer);
  public
    procedure ProcessTable;
  end;
```

При этом функция ProcessTable в обоих классах скорее всего будет одинакова, если почитаете про наследование - узнаете что с этим можно сделать))

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ. К сожалению, у меня действительно много процедур генерации. Буду пробовать)

Answer (score 1):

Модуль рисования:

Создайте класс, в котором будет описано поведение, общее для всех элементов, которые вы рисуете, а дальше наследуйте классы элементов необходимых для рисования от этого класса.

Это поможет вам избежать дублирования кода и проблем, связанных с возможными изменениями.

Например:

> ```
>     type
>     TPainter=class(TObject)
>     protected
>       procedure Paint(); virtual;
>     end;
>
>     type
>     TCircle=class(TPainter)
>     protected
>       procedure Paint(); override;
>     end;
> ```

---

Стандартные функции:

Разбейте их на "группы по интересам" и также объедините их в классы с использованием классовых функций, как указано в предыдущем ответе.

Например:
Есть функции по работе с интерфейсом пользователя:

```
     type
     TCommonUI=class(TObject)
     public
       class procedure SetWindow(...);
     end;
```

---

Старайтесь писать модули так, чтобы их можно было использовать в других проектах без каких-либо глобальных изменений. Минимизируйте зависимости, между модулями, относящимися к различным уровням приложения.

Например:
Модуль рисования объектов на форме не должен быть жестко связан с модулем работы с БД, по идее они вообще не должны зависеть друг от друга.

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий мне не дают написать, поэтому кину сюда :)

Тот самый учебник: "Объектно-ориентированное программирование"
Авторы: Иванова Г.С., Ничушкина Т.Н., Пугачев Е.К.

В нем сначала описана теория, а потом показана реализация на различных языках.